# How do I get all records from all sheets (tabs) in a google spreadsheet using one API call?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wanted to retrieve all the records from a google spreadsheet in one api call (instead of looping through all the sheets and retrieving them one-by-one). Currently I'm doing this

```
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path-to-key', 'key.json'), self.scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spread = client.open("My SpreadSheet")

data_for_sheet_0 = spread.get_worksheet(0).get_all_records()
data_for_sheet_1 = spread.get_worksheet(1).get_all_records()
.
.
.
```

As you can see, this is not efficient. Is there any way to get all of the sheet data (or the entire spreadsheet as an Iterable of Iterables)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. By using `spreadsheet.worksheets()`
Checkout this gspread documentation: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet

```
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path-to-key', 'key.json'), self.scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spread = client.open("My SpreadSheet")

#Getting a list of worksheets inside a spreadsheet.
sheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()

for sheet in sheets:
    record = sheet.get_all_records()

    # Do whatever you want
    print(record)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It specifically asks for how to do this with a single API call, not by getting a list of all worksheets and retrieving their values one by one.